# Setting up limited retries for PHP quiz

Tags: php, html

I currently am running a quiz using PHP and of you get a question wrong you have the choice to go back to the homepage and start over or retry the question. However, in doing this you can infinitely try to guess the answer. Is there any way I can set this up so lets say you can only try once more to get the correct answer? I have been trying to look it up and to be quite frank I haven't found anything at all on the subject. Here is the sample code I am using to check if the answer is correct:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Answers for Color Quiz</title>
<style>
body{
background: linear-gradient(90deg, #FFFF00, #ffae42, #FFA500,   #ff5349, #FF0000, #c71585 , #EE82EE, #8A2BE2, #0000FF, #0d98ba, #00FF00, #9ACD32);
background-size: 1800% 1800%;

-webkit-animation: rainbow 40s ease infinite;
-z-animation: rainbow 40s ease infinite;
-o-animation: rainbow 40s ease infinite;
animation: rainbow 40s ease infinite;}

@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {
0%{background-position:0% 82%}
50%{background-position:100% 19%}
100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@-moz-keyframes rainbow {
0%{background-position:0% 82%}
50%{background-position:100% 19%}
100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@-o-keyframes rainbow {
0%{background-position:0% 82%}
50%{background-position:100% 19%}
100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@keyframes rainbow { 
0%{background-position:0% 82%}
50%{background-position:100% 19%}
100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
h1{
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif; 
font-size:10em;
text-align:center;
}
#bodies{
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif; 
font-size:5em;
text-align:center;
}
input[type=text] {
-ms-transform: scale(3); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(3); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: scale(3);

}
input[type="submit"] {
-ms-transform: scale(3); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(3); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: scale(3);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Color Wheel Quiz </h1><p>
<div id=bodies>
<?php
include('colorquiz.php');
$choice=$_GET['choice'];
$right=@$_GET['right'];
$left=@$_GET['left'];
$which=$_GET['which'];
$correctright=$rightcolors[$choice];
$correctleft=$leftcolors[$choice];
if ($which=='right') {
if (metaphone($left) == metaphone($correctleft)) {
   print("Correct! $correctleft is the capital of $correctright!");
   print("<p><a href='colorquizask.php'>Play again </a>");
   }   
else {
   print("Wrong Study More!<p>\n");
   print("<a href='colorquizask.php'>Back to home </a><p>\n");
  print("OR try again: What is opposite of $correctright on the color   wheel?<br>");
 print("<form action='colorquizcheck.php' method='get'>\n");
 print("<input type='text' name='left'><br>\n");
 print("<input type='hidden' name='right' value=$right>\n");
 print("<input type='hidden' name='which' value=$which>\n");
 print("<input type='hidden' name='choice' value=$choice>\n");
 print("<input type='submit' value='Submit Answer'>");
 print("</form>\n");
}  }
else {
if (metaphone($right) == metaphone($correctright)) {
   print("Correct! The color opposite of $correctright is    $correctleft!");
   $saywhich='false';
   print("<p><a href='colorquizask.php'>Play again </a>");
   }
else {
print("Wrong Study More!<p>\n");
   print("<a href='colorquizask.php'>Back to home </a><p>\n");
  print("OR try again: $correctleft is the opposite of what color?  <br>");
 print("<form action='colorquizcheck.php' method='get'>\n");
print("<input type='text' name='right'><br>\n");
 print("<input type='hidden' name='left' value=$left>\n");
 print("<input type='hidden' name='which' value=$which>\n");
 print("<input type='hidden' name='choice' value=$choice>\n");
 print("<input type='submit' value='Submit Answer'>");
 print("</form>\n");
}  }
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The whole idea is to give you just one more try and then it would print sorry no more retries left and then it would be linked back to main page.

Comment: Use a session var http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php and increment it each submit.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion however the documentation from what I am looking up isn't too clear to me. Here is what I understand so far, I would initialize the startup of the session at the very top and for each summit I would have it end the action but not the entire startup. What I don't understand is how to set it up and what kind of if statement I would use to call what I need to do @AbraCadaver